# How to create subpanels and show up one below the other in Rebol?

Tags: rebol

The official tutorial here http://www.rebol.com/how-to/subpanels.html does show how to create panels and shows one OR the other not how to show them ALL of them one BELOW an other.

So any other article or how to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create different boxes where you want the other panels to go and set their pane's to the layout of the panel you wish to display.